# Resize image on table row hover

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, resize

Is there anyway to change the code below to expand the image when hovering over the table row?  Currently it's set up to re-size to a larger version when hovering over the independent image.

```
//HTML

<tr>
<td><img class="bigpic" src="pic.png"></td>
<td>information</td>
<td>information</td>
<td>information</td>
</tr>

//CSS

.bigpic:hover {
    width: 45px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

Comment: if you think about a pop up... you need a click event (browser blocking). however: you can also create a hidden div-box with a large image and onHover you change the visibility and the image src of that box with javascript

Comment: @Mario that seems a bit excessive just to add a hover style to a row's descendants...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tr:hover .bigpic {
    width: 45px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

Because the `hover` sudo class is applied to the table row and `bigpic` is a descendant of a `tr`, then all you have to do is add a rule for decedents of a hovered row.

this has the draw back of resizing the entire row though and it can ugly up your table. I would suggest placing a div in the table cell and absolutely positioning the image. So that it 'pops out' of the row when you hover.

[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/59aLb/) and [an example of my suggestion about the div and pop out](http://jsfiddle.net/59aLb/1/)

Comment: thank you for your advise... but how would you do it if you have more than 1 pic in your table? so i thought about javascript and one div box http://jsfiddle.net/59aLb/1/

Comment: how do you mean more than one picture? are you saying that you are afraid the pictures are going to overlap when they resize? I would suggest adding a border on the hover effect or move to a light box style of enlargement. If it is not a problem that the row re-sizes then go for it, I just personally don't like my table layouts disturbed. http://jsfiddle.net/59aLb/3/

Comment: it seems that i missunderstood the question, i thought every table cell should contain a mini-pic with a hover effect. so i preferred a solution with a big-pic before the table.

Comment: That would make sense. I may be misunderstanding it. Who knows. The OP has stopped paying any attention as far as i can tell.